Adding a choke to the feed point
I recently installed a vertical antenna and was surprised by the loud noise. I am thinking of adding a choke to the feed point, but is it sufficient to simply add one? Or should I adjust the antenna again after adding the choke?
73 Roy

It all depends on the way you set up, what frequency band(s) the antenna is for, where the noise comes from (even just the best guesses), etc. Your question lacks essential details to give meaningful answers. In general, feedline choke may reduce the noise from sources near the receiver or the feedline, but has little impact on the noises from more distant sources.

Can you identify the noise, is it atmospheric, like wide-band hash or static crashes? Is it electric motor whine, is it across the band (wide-banded) or only occurring periodically as you tune through the band?  Could it be solar panel inverter noise?  Does it sound like something arcing? What band are you experiencing this on?  Can you listen on other bands and is it in any other band?

We need more details about your vertical. Is it a ground plane with λ/4 radials? What does the coax shield connect to? What band is the antenna meant for?

Assuming coax transmission line, you'll benefit from adding a choke at the feed point to reduce radiating off the shield. You'll also benefit from adding a choke at the radio in the shack to avoid receiving noise off the shield. If you're still receiving a boatload of RFI, you can look at a noise cancelling device (either for purchase or DIY).
Anytime you add or remove components to your antenna system, it's always worthwhile to measure the before/after changes to its characteristics on your bands/frequencies of interest.
In the comments, OP notes that,

have already confirmed that the choke reduces the noise from S9 to S1. The problem is that it distorts the impedance of the well-tuned antenna.

This means that:

the coax shield was a meaningful part of the antenna RX. It's very likely that it was picking up RFI on subharmonics of the band you intended to receive and contributing greatly to your unwanted noise reception.
the coax shield was a meaningful part of the antenna TX. Whatever tuning you did leveraged the shield as part of the radiating system. Putting the choke in place at the feed point removed the coax from the system, requiring retuning.

Check out this answer to a related question and the search results on this site regarding reducing noise.

It must be emphasized that the feedline choke has no effect on the noise coming from the antenna itself, which is dominant in most cases, especially with verticals. The exception is when the noise source is much nearer to the feedline or receiver than the antenna.

Just to put a fine point on Webmarc's answer, if your antenna has any imbalances, like it isn't exactly 50 Ohm impedance for your 50 Ohm system, or the antenna isn't perfectly resonant (and any fixed antenna can't be perfectly resonant anywhere but on 1 particular frequency of any given band), you'll have reactance to deal with.  And a choke at the feed-point can prevent those currents that are not perfectly balanced with the center conductor's current, from radiating along your feed-line.  But a choke at the receiver will be more effective in attenuating noise carried on the coax shield.

Noise that is actually in the band that your antenna is tuned for, will come down the center conductor of the coax, like any other currents on the frequencies that the antenna is tuned for; and that noise is not affected by chokes on the coax shield no matter where you put them.  For in-band noise you need to look at filtering and maybe using two antennas and a phasing device to create a null of the receive pattern in the direction of the noise.

I have already confirmed that the choke reduces the noise from S9 to S1. The problem is that it distorts the impedance of the well-tuned antenna. So I asked this question.

@Roy if an external choke changes the observed impedance, then your impedance was not "well-tuned"! it means that field happening on the outside of the outer conductor of your coax is relevant to what your tuner saw as impedance, which means something can't be correctly matched.

Presence or absence of common mode current has nothing to do with the load being matched or not. They are two completely separate questions. In other words, common mode current is not generated by the load mismatch, reactance, or lack of resonance. It is completely something else. Also, whether the noise is in-band or out-of-band has nothing to do with which path (diff or comm mode) the noise conducts.

The vertical antenna feedline should have a high-impedance choke (a multi-turn winding to ensure high common mode impedance) from the beginning because a vertical antenna is very prone to common mode current, and you have no good way to tell whether you have common mode current or not. It's just easier and better to prevent it in the first place. Just adding one or two snap-on cores is insufficient. Insufficient choke can lead to power loss in the choke. It is far better to "overkill" with a high impedance choke from the beginning. What is considered high impedance enough depends on the case.
